# Python - Deleting Treeview record from table & SQLite

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I'm currently trying to make a 'delete record' button that deletes a treeview record, this part works within the treeview table, however I am unable to get the record in the SQLite database to be deleted aswell.

```
def deleterec():
try:
    curItem = tree1.focus()
    valueList=tree1.item(curItem,'values')
    global selectedItem2
    selectedItem2=valueList[0]
    prodID = tree1.selection()[0] # get selected item from tree
    messageDelete = messagebox.askyesno("Confirmation", "Do you want to permanently delete this record?")
    if messageDelete > 0:
        # Remove one record
        tree1.delete(prodID)
        print(selectedItem2) #this prints the accurate productID that's in my SQLite database
        global conn87
        conn87 = sqlite3.connect('Sqlite_Python.db')
#Create cursor instant
        global c87
        c87 = conn87.cursor()
        print("Successfully Connected to SQLite")

        sqlite_delete_queryL = str(f"""DELETE from stockDatabase WHERE productID='%s';""") % selectedItem2

        c87.execute(str(sqlite_delete_queryL))

        c87.close()
    
except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print("Error: ", error)
finally:
    if conn87:
        conn87.close()
        print("sqlite connection is closed")
```

My code is not outputting any errors and it is giving the confirmation that the connection is successfully made then closed, however the query is not complete.............  [image: The outputs including the accurate product ID]

[image]

Comment: You need to call [commit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.commit) before closing the database connection.

Comment: Awesome that worked, thanks! Have a lovely day <3